# Alexandroff Homogeneous Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I would like to know why is this true.

Theorem: Any Alexandroff $T_0$ space with nontrivial topology is not homogeneous.

I can't find a way to get to it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "nontrivial"?  Not discrete?

Comment: Nontrivial meaning not discrete and not indescrete

Comment: [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4147979/4280) is almost what you want, the local finiteness should be dropped somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Without local finiteness it need not be true:
Let ${\bf Z}$ be equipped with the topology of all upper segments.
Then for each $z \in {\bf Z}$  the map ${\bf Z} \rightarrow {\bf Z}, x \mapsto x+z$ is a homeomorphism. Hence ${\bf Z}$ is homogenous, Alexandroff, $T_0$, non-trivial.

Comment: Then he’s done. See my above comment.

Comment: So, taking into account the theorem in the link of @HennoBrandsma , and the proof it has,  I could say that any Alexandroff space, with a topology distinct to the discrete and indiscrete topology is not $T_1$?

Comment: @Henry: yes, it is true that a $T_1$ Alexandroff space is discrete. The proof is straightforward, but does neither involve my above example nor Henno's statement.